# How to convert a list word to a dictionary key and to a string at end

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a list of tuple:

```
[(133, 101, 150), (130, 99, 225), (163, 201, 196), (212, 212, 235), (248, 128, 245), (190, 239, 125), (123, 202, 119), (107, 58, 33), (161, 135, 209), (108, 105, 192)]
```

and a dictionary:

```
{'J': (133, 101, 150), 'n': (130, 99, 225), '1': (163, 201, 196), 'r': (212, 212, 235), 'S': (248, 128, 245), '8': (65, 244, 22), 'f': (22, 213, 90), 'U': (173, 66, 188)}
```

I tried and searched over the web, how to convert a list word to a dictionary key and to a string at end including all keys that are the same in the swift possible method (I use huge lists). I know that I need to use list comprehension or .''join, but i don't know how, and it was not easy to understand.

Example:
Given dictionary Keys and list of tuples, i want to obtain a string like this (done with keys that are also in list of tuples

```
data: str = Jn1rS
```

Comment: please describe the sample input and output in the question, it is not clear what you want to achieve with the given list and the dict.

Comment: Ya, I have no idea what you are asking. Please provide more detail.

Comment: ok, edited......

Comment: It's the string formed from keys of dictionary that have the same values in list of tuples

Comment: So any tuples that dont match the dict are ignored?

Comment: Yes, are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invert the dict. i.e. make the keys the values and the values the keys. This is so you can look up the letters based on the tuples.

Then you can convert all the tuples to the letters they represent (ignoring those that aren't present in the dict) and join them to make the string.

```
>>> d = {'J': (133, 101, 150), 'n': (130, 99, 225), '1': (163, 201, 196), 'r': (212, 212, 235), 'S': (248, 128, 245), '8': (65, 244, 22), 'f': (22, 213, 90), 'U': (173, 66, 188)}
>>> dd = {v: k for k, v in d.items()}
>>> tl = [(133, 101, 150), (130, 99, 225), (163, 201, 196), (212, 212, 235), (248, 128, 245), (190, 239, 125), (123, 202, 119), (107, 58, 33), (161, 135, 209), (108, 105, 192)]
>>> ''.join([dd[t] for t in tl if t in dd])
'Jn1rS'
```

Comment: The problem is time with 200mb of list and 67 elements of dictionary.

Comment: a small list pastebin.com/GFceh7gg the dictionary pastebin.com/Hkms4uK7 The most important thing, is time, doing everything in less time possibile,

Comment: I would say that the main bottleneck will be the creation of the list in the `join` line. There's no point changing that to a generator, as `join` just converts it to a list internally anyway. Possibly a good way would be to write the string to a file as its created, to avoid having it all in memory at once. Try [this](https://ideone.com/p9U0n2). Does it help? Most probably the easiest way to go is to use numpy for things like this. Feel free to provide the super large 200mb file.

Comment: Although I'd suggest that the data and output format you are using are not very amenable to efficient execution times for large inputs.

Comment: This is the dictionary: https://filebin.net/0su6l8w0bbdp5st3/dataset.txt?t=l4d755hf .
This is the list of tuples: https://mega.nz/file/QIZESDaR#pd_57SD03b0y53mo__zWAkx8X_kFrYdd0e88XgQWOFw
This is the script that I'm using: https://pastebin.com/8zcfGQPx
I don't know if I need to switch to numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over key, value pairs and pick the keys for which the values don't match.

This will do the job

```
x = [(133, 101, 150), (130, 99, 225), (163, 201, 196), (212, 212, 235), (248, 128, 245), (190, 239, 125), (123, 202, 119), (107, 58, 33), (161, 135, 209), (108, 105, 192)]

y = {'J': (133, 101, 150), 'n': (130, 99, 225), '1': (163, 201, 196), 'r': (212, 212, 235), 'S': (248, 128, 245), '8': (65, 244, 22), 'f': (22, 213, 90), 'U': (173, 66, 188)}

res = [k for k, v in y.items() if v in x]
print(''.join(res))
```

Comment: Works only with the example and not with my real list and dictionary.

Comment: would appreciate if you could share the input which is failing and I can try to fix the error

Comment: you can use https://pastebin.com/ if the data is large

Comment: a small list https://pastebin.com/GFceh7gg
the dictionary https://pastebin.com/Hkms4uK7
The most important thing, is time, doing everything in less time possibile,

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to do like this:

```
a = [(133, 101, 150), (130, 99, 225), (163, 201, 196), (212, 212, 235), (248, 128, 245), (190, 239, 125), (123, 202, 119), (107, 58, 33), (161, 135, 209), (108, 105, 192)]
b = {'J': (133, 101, 150), 'n': (130, 99, 225), '1': (163, 201, 196), 'r': (212, 212, 235), 'S': (248, 128, 245), '8': (65, 244, 22), 'f': (22, 213, 90), 'U': (173, 66, 188)}
s = ""
for (x, y) in b.items(): 
    if y in a: 
        s += x

print(s)
```

Comment: Works only with the example and not with my real list and dictionary.

Comment: But timing is good

Comment: a small list pastebin.com/GFceh7gg the dictionary pastebin.com/Hkms4uK7 The most important thing, is time, doing everything in less time possibile.